# CKQuery with NSPredicate fails when using "CONTAINS" operator

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

According to Apples Class Reference `CKQuery`, the operator `CONTAINS` is one of the supported operators. However, that doesn't seem to work. I have a `RecordType` called `myRecord`, and a record with field name `name` type `String`. I try to fetch the record with two different predicates, one with "==" operator, and one with `CONTAINS` operator.

```
func getRecords() {
    let name = "John"
    let Predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@",name)
    let Predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@",name)

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Date", ascending: false)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "myRecord", predicate: Predicate1)
    // let query = CKQuery(recordType: "myRecord", predicate: Predicate2)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.desiredKeys = ["name", "Date"]

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
        print(record["name"])

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if error == nil {

                    print ("sucess")
                } else {
                    print("couldn't fetch record error:\(error?.localizedDescription)")

                }
            }

        }

        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(operation)
    }
```

Using `Predicate1`, output is:

```
Optional(John)
sucess
```

Using `Predicate2`, output is:

```
couldn't fetch record error:Optional("Field \'name\' has a value type of STRING and cannot be queried using filter type LIST_CONTAINS")
```

Also using `[c]` to ignore casings gives a server issue.

How do I use the operator **`CONTAINS`** correctly?

**EDIT:**
I have now looked closer at the documentation, and seen that `CONTAINS` can only be used with `SELF`. Meaning that all String fields will be used for searching. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It's an exception mentioned as below:

> With one exception, the CONTAINS operator can be used only to test
>   list membership. The exception is when you use it to perform full-text
>   searches in conjunction with the self key path. The self key path
>   causes the server to look in searchable string-based fields for the
>   specified token string. For example, a predicate string of @"self
>   contains 'blue'" searches for the word “blue” in all fields marked for
>   inclusion in full-text searches. You cannot use the self key path to
>   search in fields whose type is not a string.

So, you can use 'self' instead of '%K' in order to search sub-text of string field.

[For the full document written by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquery)

Comment: has anyone got 'self contains anything' to actually work? i have searchable fields in cloudkit and results are always empty. most frustrating for something trivial in SQL.

Comment: I've since raise a support ticket with apple. They have confirmed this is a bug. I have low confidence it will be fixed as all bug reports Ive raised have been closed as duplicates and never fixed. Will report back with the radar once I've raised it.

Comment: bug raised, FB7352939